# CodeIgniter Simple Edit Category Page

Tags: codeigniter, categories

I have a list of categories with edit and delete buttons next to them, when I click the edit button I am redirected to an edit category page but now I just want to get the category name and echo it in the field so the user can edit it. Its so simple but im new to code igniter. I think i know how to get it its just returning it and echoing it in the view.

Comment: You have not provided _nearly_ enough information for this to be answered.

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch the value and set the value like this

```
<input type="text" name="category" value="<?php echo set_value('category', $category_name); ?>" size="50" />
```